# How to make Observable that emit character after 1 second of time interval

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I have just started with RxJava/android and for practice and getting started I want to make observable that emits character in string every 1 second, how can I do this? Here is what I have tried so far, its just emit string at once:

```
Observable<String> myObservable = Observable.interval(5000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .just("Hello");
```

I want hello like this first emit H after 1 second emit E and so on

Answer (score 3):

Split String "hello" into letters "h", "e", ... "o" using `flatMap()`.

`new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(string.split(""))))` constructs `List<String> letters` and `Observable.fromIterable(letters)` emits each letter to downstream.

Then `zipWith()` zips two Observables, one is letter, other is 1 second Time.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Observable.just("Hello")
            .flatMap(string -> Observable.fromIterable(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(string.split("")))))
            .zipWith(Observable.interval(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), (letter, time) -> letter)
            .subscribe(System.out::println);

    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

Prints:

```
H
e
l
l
o

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `zip` the interval with a character-producing source, such as the [`StringFlowable.characters()`](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#characters) extensions operator:

```
StringFlowable.characters("Hello world")
.zipWith(Flowable.interval(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), (a, b) -> a)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.blockingSubscribe(System.out::print, Throwable::printStackTrace, System.out::println);
```

> `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).just("Hello");`

Note that `just` is a static method that returns a new independent `Observable`, thus calling `.just()` on an instance method will have nothing to do with that previous flow.

Comment: Also didnt understand this "just is a static method that returns a new independent Observable" because if I make this observable and saving into variable of type Observable and using it any where it should be observable if its not then how will I call subscribe on it

Comment: I made Observable myObservable = Observable.range(1, 6).interval(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()); like this its emiting value after 1 second but range is not working it didnt stop on 6 it going beyond 6

Comment: `StringFlowable` is in a separate library: `com.github.akarnokd:rxjava2-extensions:0.17.8`. To understand the difference between instance methods and static methods, see what this code prints: `Observable.just("Hello").just("World").subscribe(System.out::println)`. Your IDE should mark the second `just` with a warning that you invoke a static method on an instance and such invocations largely have no effect on the instance.