# RxJava: Range operator is not working

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

For practice purpose I created stream/Observable that emits value with 1 second period, its emitting values with one second interval but it does not terminate/stops after emitting 6, its goes on emitting values.

```
Observable myObservable = Observable.range(1, 6)
            .interval(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Answer (score 1):

`interval` is a static method. What you wrote is practically just `Observable.interval(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`. Here is a [description of the difference between static and instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993077/difference-between-static-methods-and-instance-methods).

There is an operator called [`intervalRange`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#intervalRange-long-long-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) where you can specify the range of values you want to emit and the delay between them.

Comment: I understand the difference between static and instance method, wondering if it makes any difference between functionality

Comment: and what if I want to get desired result without intervalRange operator

Comment: You can use the pattern I showed in your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46787816/61158, replace `StringFlowable` with `Observable.range()`.